# Automatically paste commands in multiple processes of a screen session

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I have several bunch of `linux` commands contained in a text file, separated by `\n\n`, and I would like to automatically paste each in given screen processes. For the sake of clarity, let's say my `command.txt` simply contains :

```
#first bunch of commands:    
executable_script1.sh
mv executable_script1 directory1


#second bunch of commands:    
executable_script2.sh
mv executable_script2 directory2
```

So the first bunch of commands would run `executable_script1.sh`, after what it will move `executable_script1`. In this example, my screen contains 3 processes:

```
0$ htop
1$ bash
2$ bash
```

The name of the processes is irrelevant, the only important information is that I would like commands `N` in screen process `N$`, as `0$` is always a `htop`.

As for now, I have been copying/pasting manually each bunch of commands in the corresponding screen processes, which worked obviously, but now I will be dealing with more than 40 bunch of commands and as many screen processes. So, how could I paste the commands `N` to the `N$` screen terminal automatically? I think a `bash`/`shell` script could do the trick, but I am not fluent enough with it. I currently use a `python2` script to generate my `command.txt` file, so mind that I could create one `txt` file by bunch of commands pretty easily if needed.

Could you help me with this? Please feel free to ask for any missing information.

*PS: I also asked this question on [Unix Stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com), but this forum seems far less populated... If we find an answer here, I will invite the answerer to paste it under my Unix Stackexchange question as well, as this could help others!*

Comment: It sounds like you really need a job scheculer tool. I think you'll better spend your time looking for ways to move away from screen, as that is only giving you a way to run a command in parallel with others (yes, and display the output to a screen). but why not just save that output to a log file, which gives you many more options for monitoring and reporting on what your "system" is doing. Just IMHO . Good luck!

Comment: thank you @shellter for your insight! The thing is that I want to be able to manage (lauch, check and stop) my scripts from home as well. I have been using screen to this extent for one year or so and it fits perfectly this need. I am running calculation so the log file would be written only at the end I think. Or did you have anything else in mind?

Comment: Yes, I have used `screen` as a base for letting processes run and then checking in on them from home. But I can't imagine trying to do that with 40 projects. For you, the next step is to put things into a crontab file. A crontab enry like `59 11 1-5 * * { /path/to/script1 -f cfgFile -s[ample args...] /path/to/input/data/script1Input/* > /path/to/reports/script1/report.txt 2> /path/to/logs/script1.errslog.$(/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d.\%H\%M) ;}` wold allow you to control your input, output and error messages. You can allways login and look in your `report` or `errslog` file to see what is happening.

Comment: You can use the `less` utility for that. Read about all of its options.You can keep track of your crontab file using an sccs system (`git`?) and import and export the file to your `sccs` easily. `crontab -e` lets you "edit/create" your crontab per user. `crontab -l > /path/to/sccs/crontab.ver1.1` lets you save the file so you can edit it there separately, or just check it in.

Comment: Depending on your $$ resources, you might want to skip this step and learn how to use a real job scheduler. `autosys` is one such product. They are usually expensive. There must be an opensource scheduler, but I can't offer any names or opinions. You can do incredibly complex control of process with these. tools. If you are on a zero budget and just want to get going, then there are many Q/A here about `crontab` entries so read up on them. And check for local documentation `info crontab` or `man crontab` on your local system will show you what options are available in your local system.

Comment: To manage/stop a script, I would just rely on `kill -15 $jobPID` . You can designate a special file to hold the PID value for a running job. But you'll need to understand how many levels of processes are created for your jobs. Look at the output of `ptree` to see what I mean. You can't just blindly take the first $PID value you find to do a clean stop. OK, thats it for now. Realize that this sort of general conversation about tools is really off-topic here as a S.O. q. You might get some traction on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98569/bin-bash ...

Comment: but answering your specific needs is really a full time job, ... yours! ;-)  So good luck. and post focused Qs including sample inputs (small!), required output, your current code/output/errorMsgs and then you'll be on-topic and get a lot of help.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain further you point @shellter. I am willing to use a self made scripts only, so I will dig a bit deaper about `crontab`. Thanks again for the hint, and I will post more specific questions about the topic if needed!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info for a pretty comprehensive write up on crontab. You can always post a new Q if you get stuck. Be sure to include the smallest sample of code (crontab entry) that causes the problem. Best to include your OS information, `uname -srv` output will do. Redirect your cron entry output to a log file, i.e. `01 01 01 01 * * VAR=true /path/to/myScript args > /tmp/myScript.log 2>&1` (VAR=true is just to illustrate you can set an envVar in myScript by pre-pending it to the command). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found my answer, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064548/send-commands-to-a-gnu-screen?rq=1)! Sometimes it just takes some other keywords to find a solution, so I will answer this question in case some other fellows end up here.

### In a nutshell

Automatically paste commands in the screen with the `bash` command :

```
screen -x screen_name -p 1 -X stuff 'executable_script1.sh\n'
```

where `-p 1` refers to the `1$` screen process. Note that `\n` at the end of the command is necessary, as when you press enter after pasting a command line.

### Detailed steps

1) Create the `screen` session you want to work in (here named 'screen_name') :

```
screen -S screen_name
```

with enough processes for all the commands (in my example, `0$ htop` plus 2 processes : `1$` and `2$`). Note that you can edit `.screenrc` in your home directory so that screen sessions start with a given number of processes by default. For this example, my `.screenrc` contains :

```
screen -t htop
screen -t 
screen -t
```

2) Create bash files for every bunch of commands, to be executed by the different screen processes.

Here I have 2 files, `screen1` containing :

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -x screen_name -p 1 -X stuff 'executable_script1.sh\n'
screen -x screen_name -p 1 -X stuff 'mv executable_script1 directory1\n'
```

and `screen2` containing :

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -x screen_name -p 2 -X stuff 'executable_script2.sh\n'
screen -x screen_name -p 2 -X stuff 'mv executable_script2 directory2\n'
```

3) Paste all your commands at once in a terminal, with :

```
bash /path_to_screen1/screen1 & /path_to_screen2/screen2 &
```

You can close this terminal immediately, even if you have long run calculations, as all it does is paste the command into `screen`. Manually open your `screen` session to verify that these lines are being executed.

Needless to say, if you have a great number of commands to pass to many screen processes, you can create the bash files and paste the commands (steps 2 and 3) via a script (with `python`for instance). Also `executable_script1.sh` can contain `python` calls if needed, with `python python_script.py`, as in a normal terminal.

Hope this will help others!

Comment: Glad your persistence helped you find a solution that works for you! Good luck!